# exclude a class from jquery for each

Tags: jquery

My code is like this

```
$("a[href]").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("href").toLowerCase().indexOf("javascript:") != 0 &&     $(this).attr("class") != "to-top")
   {
      $(this).attr("href", new URI($(this).attr("href")).removeQuery("at").addQuery("at", $.cookies.get('ACCT_TYPE') != null ? $.cookies.get('ACCT_TYPE') : "erhverv"));
  }
});
```

now i want to avoid a specific link from this condition ."a" links comes 'under tax-switch' class. is there any short cuts to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @vivek has said, use the `not` function:

```
$('a[href]').not('.tax-switch').each(
```

This'll select all anchors that do not have the class 'tax-switch'.

Comment: That's the `not` function, not the `not` selector.

Answer (score 3):

try this code , Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuCSC/)

```
$("a[href]:not(.tax-switch)").each(function () {
   $("#myDIV").append('<p>'+ $(this).html()+'</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user jquery not selector. 
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`:

```
$('a[href]').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).hasClass('tax-switch');
}).each(function(){
    // do your stuff
});
```

References:

- `filter()`.